# Declaring a pointer using regex in C

Tags: c

Regular expression in C.

Can I declare a pointer like `void *{a,b}` which means `void *a, *b;`

Is it possible, are regex expressions a standard in ANSI C

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: No, you also have to be careful with `void* a, b;` - only `a` is a pointer here.

Comment: Lol @szczurcio, very nice :D. Now Shashank Gandham, one problem per thread please. Since you intitulated this thread "Declaring a pointer in C", open another thread to discuss about regex, please.

Comment: @Danny_ds indeed, and `void b;` is not even a valid declaration.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Oh yes, of course - I overlooked that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C does not have support for regular expressions in the code itself.  Libraries exist to perform regular expressions on text, but not on the code.

Variable declarations must be done separately.  For pointers in particular, a `*` next to a declared variable applies only to that variable.  For example:

```
int *a, b, *c;
```

This declares `a` and `c` as `int *` and `b` as `int`.  Another way of looking at is that `*a`, `b`, and `*c` are all of type `int`.